# "undefined reference to 'sqrtf'" error when using makefile with -lm in C

Tags: c, math, makefile

I written two C programs which are both compiled using one Makefile (see below).  The Makefile makes use of `LDFLAGS = -O3 -lm -L/usr/lib` including -lm which aims to link the math module.

In one of my programs I use the sqrtf() function and have declared the math module for the program in question using `<math.h>`.

When compiling my Makefile in MacOS, no errors are returned and it seems to work fine.  However when compiling in Linux I get the error "undefined reference to 'sqrtf'".

What do I need to do to get my Makefile to compile without errors?

```
CC = gcc


CFLAGS = -Wall -O3 -fstrict-aliasing 

LDFLAGS = -O3 -lm -L/usr/lib

all: encoder decoder

SRC_E=encoder.c
OBJ_E=$(SRC_E:.c=.o)

SRC_D=decoder.c
OBJ_D=$(SRC_D:.c=.o)

encoder: $(OBJ_E)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $^

decoder: $(OBJ_D)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $^

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $(CFLAGS)  $^

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJ_E) $(OBJ_D) encoder decoder
```

Answer (score 2):

The library options should be after the object files:

```make
CC = gcc


CFLAGS = -Wall -O3 -fstrict-aliasing 

LDFLAGS = 
LDLIBS = -lm

all: encoder decoder

SRC_E=encoder.c
OBJ_E=$(SRC_E:.c=.o)

SRC_D=decoder.c
OBJ_D=$(SRC_D:.c=.o)

encoder: $(OBJ_E)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS)

decoder: $(OBJ_D)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $(CFLAGS)  $^

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJ_E) $(OBJ_D) encoder decoder
```

Comment: Thanks very much!  I will have a go at implementing that now!

Comment: @Hallonmallic It may be better to change `LIBS` to `LDLIBS` though as that is one of the standard make variables.

Comment: @Hallonmallic Regarding your suggested edit, `-L/usr/lib` belongs in the same variable as `-lm`, but /usr/lib should be in the standard library path anyway so is not needed. `-O3`  doesn't really belong in `LDFLAGS`.

Comment: Thanks very much again for your help!  Where would you recommend `-O3` to be kept?

Comment: I will change LIBS to LDLIBS!

Comment: Remove `$(CFLAGS)` from `encoder:` and `decoder:` target commands

Comment: Thanks @CraigEstey, where should `$(CFLAGS)` be called?  Only in the `%.o: %.c` part?

Comment: @Hallonmallic Right. `$(CFLAGS)` for `%.o: %.c` (which because of the `-c` _compiles_ to produce `.o` files). And _just_ `$(LDFLAGS)` for `encoder:/decoder:` which _just_ do _linking_ (of `.o` files to produce the executable). The way you're doing it is a good/clean/general way. By contrast: a simple combined compile and link (e.g.): `cc -o myprogram myprogram.c $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)` (Notice: there is _no_ `-c` so no `.o` is produced). This _does_ need _both_ types of flags.

Comment: @CraigEstey makes sense!  Thanks v much!

Comment: @CraigEstey Thanks. I have edited my answer accordingly.